# Add GROUPBY COUNT(*) to UNION ALL Query in SQLAlchemy - EXCEPT Equivalent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have a query which performs a UNION ALL operation on two SELECT statements in SQLAlchemy. It looks like this,

```
union_query = query1.union_all(query2)
```

What I want to do now is to perform a GROUPBY using several attributes and then get only the rows where `COUNT(*)` is equal to 1. How can I do this?

I know I can do a GROUPBY like this,

```
group_query = union_query.group_by(*columns)
```

But, how do I add the `COUNT(*)` condition?

So, the final outcome should be the equivalent of this query,

```
SELECT * FROM (
<query1>
UNION ALL
<query2>) AS result
GROUP BY <columns>
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Additionally, I would also like to know if I can get only the distinct values of a certain column from the result. That would be the equivalent of this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT <column> FROM (
<query1>
UNION ALL
<query2>) AS result
GROUP BY <columns>
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

These are basically queries to get only the unique results of two SELECT statements.

Note: The easiest way to accomplish this is to use EXCEPT or EXCEPT ALL, but my database is running on MariaDB 8 and therefore, these operations are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query, try the following where the `final_query` is the query you want to run.

```py
union_query = query1.union_all(query2)
group_query = union_query.group_by(*columns)
final_query = group_query.having(func.count() == 1)
```

For the second query, try the following.

```py
union_query = query1.union_all(query2)
group_query = union_query.group_by(*columns)
subquery = group_query.having(func.count() == 1).subquery()
final_query = query(<column>, subquery).distinct()
```

References

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.having
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-20-query-distinct
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries